# R's trunc and round not working for class Date?

Tags: r, date, truncation

Judging from the documentation, I feel like I should be able to use round and trunc for "Date" objects. However, it seems to be working only when I first convert it to "POSIXct".

```r
> d <- as.Date('2019-10-21')
> trunc(d,'months')
[1] "2019-10-21"
> trunc(as.POSIXct(d),'months')
[1] "2019-10-01 CEST"
> round(as.POSIXct(d),'months')
[1] "2019-11-01 CET"
> round(d,'months')
Error in round.default(18190, "months") : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I expected the same output for both the date and posix classes. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Since [R 4.2.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html), it is now possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon re-reading the documentation it is clear to me that the documented behaviour is different for the "Date" and "POSIXt" class. The `units` arguments is omitted in the usage example for "Date". I just misinterpreted the documentation the first time I read it. You have to first convert to POSIX to be able to round and trunc with respect to a unit.

`?trunc.Date`

> #### S3 method for class 'POSIXt'
>
> trunc(x,
>        units = c("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "months", "years"),
>        ...)
>
> #### S3 method for class 'Date'
>
> trunc(x, ...)

and also:

> The methods for class "Date" are of little use except to remove fractional days.

Comment: Sadly, I have had this trip me up multiple times. On previous occasions I eventually figured it out from the documentation, but this time I needed StackOverflow. Thank you for documenting your Q&A here!

Answer (score 0):

`?trunc`

> trunc takes a single numeric argument x and returns a numeric vector containing the integers formed by truncating the values in x toward 0.
>
> round rounds the values in its first argument to the specified number of decimal places (default 0).

```r
d <- as.Date('2019-10-21')
class(d)
#[1] "Date"
```

Regarding the `POSIXct` class, probably it has got to do with them being a number of seconds since origin.

I usually use `r-base` functions or not in the purpose they are intended unless it has to do with testing the unintended.